# How do I register an interception injection for interfaces which inherit a marker interface?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, aop, interception

For example I would like to call the following code to register a whole set of services which I want to inject a policy for:

```
container
            .AddNewExtensionIfNotPresent<Interception>().Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<IBusinessService>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
```

Where:

```
ISomeServiceA  : IBusinessService
ISomeServiceB : IBusinessService etc
```

I think I read that you **cant** get from ISomeServceX to IMarkerInterface somewhere....
Can this be confirmed.

Comment: I can use reflection and a generic extension method.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, look at loaded assemblies (add extra filtering if required - no caching if this is done on bootstrap)  Add default interceptors for the types implementing the designated marker interface.

```
        container.AddNewExtensionIfNotPresent<Interception>();
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsClass && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.GetType() != typeof(T)).ToArray();
            foreach (Type t in types)
            {
                container.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor(t, new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

The above can be done using the fluent API and means we dont have the naiive dependency on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() (which wouldnt contain the filtering applied in the fluent api config

```
.Include(If.Implements<IBusinessService>, (x, y) =>
                                                          {
                                                              if (x.IsClass)
                                                                  y.Configure<Interception>().
                                                                      SetDefaultInterceptorFor(x,
                                                                                               new VirtualMethodInterceptor
                                                                                                   ());
                                                          })
```

Comment: would you happen to know how to write this in vb.net?